# HP DL360 G7 4K native sector disk size compatible?

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, advanced-format

I have a HP DL360 G7 server with a P410i drive controller which don't accept 4K native sector size disks (Seagate ST2000NX0263). LED on drive bay is red.
Is there any controller (Adaptec, LSI, Intel ..) which is compatible with the server and the 4K native disks?
I have tried the disks in a HP DL160 Gen9 with Smart Array P440 which states the 4Kn drive is not available for configuration even if it sees it. Don't know why but perhaps HP don't support 4K native?

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility that the disks you've tried are defective? Or that you have them in a mixed configuration on the same backplane as SAS disks which might be unsupported?

Comment: Hi, the disks are new and unused. None other disks in the DL360.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason you're not using HP disks in this server? I'm assuming you're using these Seagate SAS drives for capacity, since 7200 RPM 2.5" disks are usually a bad proposition and can cost more than 900GB 10k SAS...

Either way, these servers/onboard controllers were not designed for 4k disks. If you're using a G7 system with a P410, just stick to the compatibility list.

I wouldn't change the RAID controller either. Try making sure the firmware is fully up-to-date on the RAID controller first.

The current version [as of this writing is 6.64](http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=4091567&swItemId=MTX_2fe5ac5b7d9d489088825f3a4e&swEnvOid=4103#tab-history).

Comment: These disks were reduntant and i hoped i could use them in a storage/staging server. I have used other Seagate's not 4K without problem in DL 360 G7's but hoped someone had success using 4K disks and could tell how they did it. Perhaps another raid-controller from Adaptec, LSI, Intel .... is compatible with G7's and 4K native.

Comment: @rusk Try upgrading the firmware on the RAID controller. What's the current firmware level?

Comment: The firmware for the P410i is 6.64. Have just installed HP Service Pack for ProLiant 2015.10.0 without any difference, so i guess i have to get another controller but which is compatible with 360G7 and 4K, perhaps Adaptec RAID 7805 which is 4K ready, but it is not listed as compatible with G7.